# What happens to lock's state and methods when a thread acquires a lock?

Tags: java, multithreading

Assume I have following class

```
class Student{
   void method1(){
     // Do Something
   }
   void method2(){
     // Do Something
   }
```

}

And the object of this class is used as monitor in synchronization in some piece of the code as

```
class ProcessingThread implements Runnable {
   void someMethod(){
     synchronized(student){    // student object is used as lock. Thread T1 acquires a lock on student.
       // critical section of code
     }
   }
}
```

When a thread T1 acquires a lock on the student object, and enters into the critical section of the code, at the same time can some another thread T2 executes a method on the student object i.e.

```
class College{
   void assignTopic(){
      student.method1();   // Thread T2 working on student object when 
                           // Thread T1 has acquired a lock on student
   }
}
```

I want to know that what happens to the methods / variables of the locked object when it is acquired by a thread?

Comment: ["Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it. ..."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Comment: It is implementation specific. On Linux, read [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens when a thread acquires a lock?

No other thread can acquire that lock until it's released.

Note that this is **all** that happens. Only methods called via *other threads* are affected. Only other threads that compete for *the same lock* are affected at all.

This means that the holding thread can do whatever it likes, just as before the lock. Other threads cannot acquire that lock, but they can do everything else. That includes mutating the state of `student`, unless *all* of `student's` mutating methods and fields are protected by *the same lock*. If there is a mutating method that isn't `synchronized`, or synchronizes via a different lock, the "locked" object can still change unpredictably.

To elaborate: as ratchet freak's answer says, obtaining a lock on an object doesn't protect it from changing *unless all possible users pledge to obtain the same lock before changing it*. This is hard to enforce because most languages don't have built-in support for questions of mutability, only for locking. It can also lead to problems because obtaining multiple locks can easily cause deadlock; you need a clear policy in which order to obtain locks, and everyone has to follow them all the time. Again, this is easy to get wrong, and few languages give you any support enforcing it.

This is why reasoning about thread-safety is hard: a single chink in the armor completely negates all consistency assertions you wanted to make, and thread-safety is not preserved under composition (two components that were proven to be thread-safe might not be thread-safe when used together, for instance because they use **different** locks and not the same one).

Comment: @GlenH7 I have updated the question. Please check. Could you please elaborate on "That includes mutating the state of student, unless all of student's mutating methods and fields are protected by the same lock." Did you meant, when thread T1 has acquired a lock on student, thread T2 can work on student objects methods simultaneously?  Is there an performance impact. It would be great,if you could update your answer instead  of replying to this comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure safety *both threads* must go and acquire the lock before messing with the data of student.

If one thread doesn't do that then it's like neither thread acquired the lock.

Part of acquiring the lock is waiting until no other thread has the lock.